# Efficient embedding computations for large DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

Given the `DataFrame`:

```
    id  articleno           target
0   1   [607303]            607295
1   1   [607295]            607303
2   2   [243404, 617953]    590448
3   2   [590448, 617953]    243404
```

for each row, compute the **average** article-embedding by looking up each item in the lists in the dictionary:

```
embeddings = {"607303": np.array([0.19, 0.25, 0.45])
             ,"607295": np.array([0.77, 0.76, 0.55])
             ,"243404": np.array([0.35, 0.44, 0.32])
             ,"617953": np.array([0.23, 0.78, 0.24])
             ,"590448": np.array([0.67, 0.12, 0.10])}
```

So for example, and to clarify, for the third row (index 2), the article embeddings for `243404` and `617953` is `[0.35, 0.44, 0.32]` and `[0.23, 0.78, 0.24]`, respectively. The average article embedding is computes as the element wise addition of all elements, divided by the number of articles, so: `([0.35, 0.44, 0.32]+[0.23, 0.78, 0.24])/2=[0.29, 0.61, 0.28]`.

**Expected output:**

```
    id  dim1     dim2     dim3      target
0   1   0.19     0.25     0.45      607295
1   1   0.77     0.76     0.55      607303
2   2   0.29     0.61     0.28      590448
3   2   0.45     0.45     0.17      243404
```

**In reality**, my `DataFrame` has millions of rows, and the lists in `articleno` can contain many more items. Because of this, iterating over the rows might be too slow, and a more **efficient** solution (perhaps vectorized) could be needed.

**Moreover**, the number of dimensions (embedding size) is known beforehand, but is a couple of hundred, so the number of columns; `dim1`, `dim2`, `dim3`, `...` `dimN` should be **dynamic**, based on the dimensions of the embedding (`N`).

Comment: This makes your previous question really an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can solve the problem from the original data a lot easier.

Comment: @QuangHoang Could you expand a bit? I'm open for ideas on how to construct the data-preprocessing in a more efficient manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the previous question, you went extra miles to separate elements in `articleno` list, then remove the `target` from `articleno` list. Now, if you want to access the elements inside `articleno` list, you need to go extra miles again to separate them.

To illustrate what I mean, here's an approach that generate both of the output from the two questions, while adding minimal extra code:

```
# construct the embeddings dataframe:
embedding_df = pd.DataFrame(embeddings).T.add_prefix('dim')

# aggregation dictionary
agg_dict = {'countrycode':'first','articleno':list}

# taking mean over embedddings
for i in embedding_df.columns: agg_dict[i] = 'mean'

new_df = df.explode('articleno')

(new_df.join(new_df['articleno'].rename('target'))
    .query('articleno != target')
    .merge(embedding_df, left_on='articleno', right_index=True)  # this line is extra from the previous question
    .groupby(['id','target'], as_index=False)
    .agg(agg_dict)
)
```

Output:

```
   id  target countrycode         articleno  dim0  dim1  dim2
0   2  590448          US  [617953, 617953]  0.23  0.78  0.24
1   2  617953          US  [590448, 590448]  0.67  0.12  0.10
```

---

Now, if you don't care for `articleno` column in the final output, you can even simplify your code while lower memory/runtime like this:

```
total_embeddings = g[embedding_df.columns].sum()
article_counts = g['id'].transform('size')

new_df[embedding_df.columns] = (total_embeddings.sub(new_df[embedding_df.columns])
                                  .div(article_counts-1, axis=0)
                               )
```

and you would get the same output.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate response. Another detail, when you create the `agg_dict` with `mean`, I would also like to change it to `absmax`- in order to get not only average embeddings, but also max embeddings (but max in absolute values) Of course, this does not work (since `absmax` doesn't exist). I've tried to use a function instead of a string, such as `lambda x: x.abs().idxmax()`, but this is both horrendously slow and does not work as expected. Do you have any suggestion?